# Why there is no uniform prior for Box-Cox Power Transformed Normal Models

Tags: probability, bayesian, normal-distribution, data-transformation, uninformative-prior

I am trying to get intuition why uniform prior like below will not work for the box-cox model.

Box-cox model: $y^{(\phi)}_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$ where

$y^{(\phi)}_i = (y^{\phi}_i-1)/\phi $    if $\phi \ne 0$  Or $ln$ $y_i$    otherwise

For the above transformation $P(\mu,\sigma,\phi) \propto 1/\sigma $ is not an uniform prior. Why? I have a vague sense that if original $y_i$ is scaled, then the prior is no longer uniform. I tried to read original Box-Cox(1964) paper but failed to get correct intuition.

Comment: This  is related, maybe even a duplicate:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147190/bayesian-analysis-of-box-cox-transformation

Answer (score 4):

The problem with that "model" is that it is'nt really, really a model!  This was discussed at length in McCullaghs (2000) paper "What is a statistical model?" http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1035844977    which I am not going to review here. (He finds that to answer the question, he needs quite advanced mathematics, specifically, category theory).  So I will try to give a simpler explanation of that (which basically is the reason given by Box and Cox themselves).

When you vary the transform parameter $\phi$, then you *change the measurement scale of $y$ itself*.  Lets say that the original data $y$ (corresponding to transform parameter $\phi=1$) is measured in meter (m). 
Then, when  $\phi=1/2$, $y$ is square root of meter (whatever that may be!) and if $\phi=2$ y is now square meter! So, not only the scale, but the *meaning* of the two other parameters $\mu, \sigma$ change when $\phi$ is changing (That is, their *unit of measurement* change).  This argument could be seen as an application of *dimensional analysis*, an underused tool in statistics.

So, maybe we should say that the "boxcox model" is not  a model, but a *family of models indexed by $\phi$*.  If you want a Bayesian treatment of this (probably not a very good idea?) you must give separate prior distributions for $\mu, \sigma$ for each value of $\phi$ (they should of course be correctly related).  Say you have a prior of the form $\propto 1/\sigma$ when $\phi=1$, then for other values of $\phi$ the prior distribution could be calculated (try it!) and it would be quite different.

If that is worth it, or practical, I do not know, but it could be interesting to try.