# Optimal values of lambda in box-cox transformations do not lead to the lowest SSE?

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, linear, model-comparison

I am using R to find optimal values of Lambda in Box-Cox transformations.
you can find the data I am using here:

```
https://uwyo-files.instructure.com/courses/449832/files/36678098/course%20files/CH03PR15.txt?download=1&inline=1&sf_verifier=8db02990e8a79f78c9ff4418589ec229&ts=1456693144&user_id=569842
```

I have named the data "C15"

I used typical code to find the SSE for values of lambda in increments of 1 from -2 to positive 2.

```
C15$CONCENTRATION <- C15$V1
C15$HOURS <- C15$V2
C15 <- C15[,(3:4), drop=F]
attach(C15)
require(MASS)
library(MASS)
hourfit <- lm(CONCENTRATION~HOURS)
bchourfit <- boxcox(hourfit)
#chart indicates somewhere around 0 is the best value for lambda.
C15$concneg2 <- CONCENTRATION^(-2)
    C15$concneg1 <- CONCENTRATION^(-1)
C15$conczero <- CONCENTRATION^0
    C15$concplus1 <- CONCENTRATION^1
C15$concplus2 <- CONCENTRATION^2
attach(C15)
concfitneg2 <- lm(concneg2~HOURS)
concfitneg1 <- lm(concneg1~HOURS)
concfitzero <- lm(conczero~HOURS)
concfitplus1 <- lm(concplus1~HOURS)
concfitplus2 <- lm(concplus2~HOURS)
aov(concfitneg2)
aov(concfitneg1)
aov(concfitzero)
aov(concfitplus1)
aov(concfitplus2)
install.packages("AID")
library("AID")
boxcoxfr(CONCENTRATION,HOURS)
```

From the ANOVA tables you can see that the lowest Sum of Squared error in the residuals comes from a lambda value of 0. However, I now use a function which finds the optimal value of lambda. It now indicates that the optimal value is .14, which is consistent with the log-likelihood graph before. However, when an ANOVA table is generated for the linear model with a transformation of .14, the Sum of Squared error is larger than the model that uses a transformation of zero.

```
install.packages("AID")

library("AID")
attach(C15)
boxcoxfr(CONCENTRATION,HOURS)
C15$concopti <- CONCENTRATION^(.14)
attach(C15)
concoptifit <- lm(concopti~HOURS)
aov(concoptifit)
aov(concfitzero)
```

Why does the optimal value of Lambda not also give the lowest SSE?

Comment: Because you potentially overfit. The optimal $\lambda$ for the Box-Cox transform is in no way related with the optimal SSE for your regression model. That being said the (not horribly essentially) assumption of linear model is that the *residuals* are normally distributed, not the dependent variables; so I cannot see why you care about transforming the dependent variable with such a strong transformation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparisons does'nt make sense! The boxcox transform will change the scale of your data values, so the SSE (sum square error) values are on different scales, so not comparable.  See [Why there is no uniform prior for Box-Cox Power Transformed Normal Models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122393/why-there-is-no-uniform-prior-for-box-cox-power-transformed-normal-models/263704#263704).

This is also a problem when estimating an optimal $\lambda$, which is solved by introducing a Jacobian, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform). The same could be applied to get comparable sum of squares.